# Regex to parse labels and values from string

Tags: regex

I'm trying figure a way to parse out the labels and values from a long string using a regular expresssion.
For example:

```
Label1: 04/03/21  Label2: 03/25/21  OZZIE Label3: WLD1963
```

I'd like to match and capture the following:

- Label1: 04/03/21
- Label2: 03/25/21  OZZIE
- Label3: WLD1963

The problem is that the label names are arbitrary.  They could be anything.  The only constant is that there is a colon at the end of each label. I've tried various expressions, but I just don't seem to have the imagination required to pull this off.  Any takers??  
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the various expressions that you have tried?

Comment: Does it have to be a regular expressions? Couldn't you split on space characters and then group together labels and their values?

Comment: Are labels always preceeded by two space characters like in your sample input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to split on space characters and then use the parts of the string to match labels to their values. Should be as simple as a simple for-loop and two arrays. Simple to write, test, understand, and maintain.

If you *must* do it with a regular expression, it should be possible to extract the parts by using a negative lookahead:

```
(\S+): ((?:(?! \S+:).)+)
```

Breakdown:

- `(\S+):` match any number of non-space characters before a colon and capture in group
- `(?:(?! \S+:).)` match a single character that is not a space followed by non-spaces and a colon

  - `(?!…)` is a negative lookahead
  - `(?:…)` is a non-capturing group
- `((?:…)+)` repeat the single-character match and capture in group

https://regex101.com/r/sik3sq/1

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to use your negative lookahead expression.  Test Code:

        `Dim strRegex As String = "(\S+): ((?:(?! \S+:).)+)"
        Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.Singleline)
        Dim strTargetString As String = "Label1: 04/03/21  Label2: 03/25/21  OZZIE Label3: WLD1963"

        For Each myMatch As Match In myRegex.Matches(strTargetString)
            If myMatch.Success Then
                MsgBox(myMatch.Value.ToString)
            End If
        Next`

Answer (score 1):

Regex doesn’t “parse”. It only matches.

You could however match what’s between terms and split the input:

Here’s some Java code that would do that:

```
String[] parts = str.split(" +(?=\\w+:");
```

Or, you could match each term:

```
\b\w+: +(.(?! +\\w+:))+
```

And iterate over the matches.

Whatever you do, you’ll need a tool or app language.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, here I show a little example doing it with "split" and "for loop" as @knittl said:

```
content = 'Label1: 04/03/21 Label2: 03/25/21 OZZIE Label3: WLD1963'
content_l = [c.strip() for c in content.split(':')]
answer = content_l[0]
for c in content_l[1:-1]:
    c_splitted = c.split(' ')
    descr = ' '.join(c_splitted[0:-1])
    answer += f": {descr}\n{c_splitted[-1]}"
answer += f": {content_l[-1]}\n"
print(answer)
```

And you'll get:

```
Label1: 04/03/21
Label2: 03/25/21 OZZIE
Label3: WLD1963
```